# R table mean of 1 var over other variables

Tags: r

I cant seem to find how to make a simple table with the mean of one variable over other categorical variables. So I want the mean of var1 (ratio 0-100) over var2 and var3 (both dummy with value 1 and value 2). in a simple table below each other. so var 1 in the column and var2 and var3 in the rows.
I thought maybe the compareGroups package could help but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Please [edit as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using base R with the `mtcars` data set:

```
aggregate(mpg ~ am, data = mtcars,mean)
```

...and the output:

```
> aggregate(mpg ~ am, data = mtcars,mean)
  am      mpg
1  0 17.14737
2  1 24.39231
>
```

A `dplyr` solution looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% summarise(mean = mean(mpg))
> mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% summarise(mean = mean(mpg))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
     am  mean
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0  17.1
2     1  24.4
>
```

Comment: Thank you, this totally works. I am new to R so this is really helpful!

Comment: @es_dutch - If the answer was helpful, please accept and upvote it. Thanks!

Comment: Is there also a possiblity to perform a t-test to compare the means and see if they are significantly different?

Comment: @es_dutch - Yes there is: `t.test(mpg ~ am,data = mtcars)` . BTW, there are a number of resources to help you learn R, such as those I list in [References for R Programming](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-References.md)

Comment: Thank you! It is a lot to figure out.